# Why is my program failing for numbers larger than 2^29?

Tags: c++, types, cuda

I made the following program that takes a list 'a' of length 2^i (initialized as all 1's), and adds all the numbers it contains together. When i is at least 30, it returns a nonsensical answer. I don't understand why, I used long's for everything and on my machine the size of a long is 8 bytes = 64 bits, so I would say that it must be able to hold integers up to 2^(8 * 8)/2.

```
// FOR NOW ONLY WORKS WITH N A POWER OF 2
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

/* 
Parallel reduce helper function. When run 
with n/2 threads, adds a[n - 1 - i] to a[i]
for i = 0, ..., n - 1.
*/
__global__ void reduce(long* a, long n)
{
    long i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    long stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    for (long j = i; j < n/2; j += stride)
    {
        a[j] += a[n - 1 - j];
    }
}

/* 
For an array a of length n, puts the sum of all elements in a[0]
*/
void parallelReduce(long* a, long n)
{
    // Get some information about the GPU
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
    int multiProcessors = prop.multiProcessorCount;

    // Repeatedly use the helper function reduce
    while (n > 1) {
        int threadsPerBlock = 256;
        int numberOfBlocks = 32 * multiProcessors;
        reduce << <numberOfBlocks, threadsPerBlock >> > (a, n);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        n = (n + n % 2) / 2; // Rounds n/2 up.
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize vector with N 1's.
    long N = 2 << 28;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(long);
    long* h_a;
    cudaMallocHost(&h_a, size);

    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = 1;
    }

    // Copy to device (can be done asynchronically to hide transfer time, but 
    // that messes up the timing of the kernel).
    long* d_a;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Calculate the sum sequentially and time it.
    auto tic = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long hostSolution = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hostSolution += h_a[i];
    }
    auto toc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(toc - tic).count();

    std::cout << "The sequential function says the answer is " << hostSolution << " this took " << duration
        << " ms." << std::endl;

    // Kernel computation
    tic = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parallelReduce(d_a, N);
    toc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int parallelDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(toc - tic).count();

    // Copy result back to host
    long solution;
    cudaMemcpy(&solution, &d_a[0], sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print the parallel result and speed up:
    std::cout << "The parallel function says the answer is " << solution << " this took " << parallelDuration
        << " ms." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "This means we have achieved a speed up of " << duration / parallelDuration << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you running? If it is Windows, `sizeof (long) == sizeof (int)`. Generally speaking , avoid `long`, as its portability is poor. Try `uint64_t` instead of `long`. Also, watch out for overflow in intermediate computations, e.g. `2 << 28` would want to be `2ULL << 28`.

Comment: I'm with njuffa here. `uint64_t` is not subject to interpretation. `long` is fairly arbitrary.

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. There is too much code here and I was not able to find the part that was relevant to your question.

Comment: Pay some attention to how big your array is getting.  At 2³⁰ elements, `size` reaches 8GB.  Why aren't you checking the return values of `cuda*` functions for errors, particularly `cudaMallocHost` and `cudaMalloc` ?  Also note that 2³⁰ is written in C++ as `1U << 30` and not `2U << 30`

Comment: You may want to consider using `uint32_t` or `int32_t` which are guaranteed to be 32 bits wide.

Comment: Support of `uint32_t`, `int32_t`, `uint64_t` is not exactly great either,  since they are *optional* from C++11 (not supported by all implementations) and non-standard before then.   In any event, in using cuda, you are giving up some element of portability - the onus is to on you to ensure compatibility between your compiler (and types it supports), the cuda API, and your usage of it.   Simply using `long` (or any other type) everywhere is not a recipe for success.

Comment: @Peter: CUDA's headers relies on these types being available though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a dupe, but I can't find another question to pin it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can, you just need to the correct types. Compile and execute the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Max int value: " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Max long value: " << std::numeric_limits<long>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Max long long value: " << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Your output depends on your ide/architecture/compiler flags and other things, for me it is's the following.

```
Max int value: 2147483647
Max long value: 2147483647
Max long long value: 9223372036854775807
```

As for why 'When i is at least 30, it returns a nonsensical answer', overflow is UB, and you can't relay on what compiler will do in such case.

Comment: Huh, okay. Strange that the max long value is the same as the max int value. But then that is the issue.

Comment: @PeldePinda Integer size requirements are basically minimums and very flexible to accommodate various architectures. The actual representable range varies from platform to platform. See the requirements [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties).

Comment: @PeldePinda: That's not the issue, because even a 32-bit signed integer can hold 2³⁰ just fine.  Your problem is most likely that your array gets big enough that allocation fails.